# Determining probability density function in Brownian motion simulation

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, brownian-motion

Theoretically, the probability density function of brownian particle would be a function satisfy the diffusion equation in the form of:
\begin{equation}
\rho=\frac{N}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}e^{\frac{x^2}{4Dt}}
\end{equation}
I am simulating a big particle undergoing collision with small particles, which is Brownian motion, inside a box. Is there any way to get me the probability density function of the particle?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Do you mean that you've already simulated a system and you want to numerically determine a PDF? You could pick a dt and a number of times t, and then see the distribution of the particle after a time dt. Of course you'll need to make some uniformity assumptions here and make sure the t are far enough apart so as to not have the measurements correlated. Alternatively you could start with different initial conditions (for the solute). The time and ensemble averages should match if the systek is ergodic.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. Yes, I have already simulated a system and wanna determine the PDF numerically. However, I am not sure if my model is correct, because I just put one Brownian particle in the box. I guess that might not be enough. Do I have to add more than 1 Brownian partlcle?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me here what you're trying to achieve. If you want the PDF of a particle diffusing in a box, probably the more computationally efficient way of doing it is just to solve the Fokker-Planck equation. You can use a single particle if your timescales are long enough (the trajectory has no memory, so you can just numerically compute the conditional of it being in a specific place - to within numerical tolerance), or you can use several (it'll depend on whether your dynamics are actually stochastic or if everything is deterministic as to how to set up the initial conditions)

Comment: Thanks for the advice and sorry for the late reply. You were right, I am trying to get the PDF of a particle diffusing in a box. Actually, my project is to get the diffusion coefficient and plug it in the diffusion equation. Then, the equation could be solved numerically and I could have a look at the behaviour of function. Meanwhile, I also want to get the function directly from my box simulation instead of solving it. Then I could compare the function obtained by twp methods.

Comment: However, I later found myself misunderstood the diffusion equation for Brownian motion.The function should be a density function instead of a provability density function. So the question posted here may cause confusion.